# Создание окна с текстом в библиотеке классов c#

Tags: c#, dll, textarea, окно

У меня есть библиотека классов, мне нужно создать окно, которое будет постоянно показываться. Там должно быть многострочное поле с текстом, текст которого я буду обновлять из кода. По какой-то причине решения не нашел.

Comment: Библиотека - это дополнительный функционал для приложения (разные утилиты, методы вспомогательные, либо вовсе core (базовые функции) приложения). Интерфейсы (в WPF это зовется View) "запихивать" в библиотеки как по мне - глупая и не правильная идея.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ модульные приложения как раз хранят интерфейс в библиотеках-модулях, а точка входа - просто пустой шелл с кодом инициализации

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  почему? Если например хочется собрать библиотеку своих контролов, то их всегда вручную тягать из проекта в проект?

Comment: Я пишу скрипт для GTA 5, мне нужно окно с дебагом

Comment: @tym32167 @ yolosora Пожалуй соглашусь, забыл про такие вещи. Я имел ввиду обычное приложение, которое имело бы основное Form/Window в dll. Как по мне такое все же перебор. да и вон автор говорит "окно с дебагом", ведь делается это путем уже имеющегося в той же игре. а не написанием какого то интерфейса в dll.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Проблема в том, что я не знаю никакого способа дебага в GTA 5 (мне нужно писать там свои сообщения).